# Python json.dumps not working in for loop

Tags: python, json

Below code scans the folders and list all the files older than threshold date. For instance of the threshold time is now-12hrs then it will list all the files older than threshold and save them in variable.

```
string_output = ""
my_paths = []
for p in ['\\\location\\folderpath\\subfolder\\']:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(p):
        my_paths.append(filenames)
        for filename in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            if last_modified(full_path) < threshold:
                string_output+= '\n{}\n{}\n{}\nFile Name: {}\nFile Size: {}\nFile Created: {}\nFile Last Modified: {}\n{}'.format(
                separator, timestamp, app_name, full_path,
                file_size(full_path),
                created(full_path),
                last_modified(full_path),separator)
print string_output;
```

string format output looks good without extra backslah

```
----------------------------------------
09/06/2017 13:10:07
File Name: \\location\folderpath\subfolder\1.txt
File Size: 153.0 bytes
File Created: 2017-01-26 14:29:59
File Last Modified: 2017-01-26 14:28:39
----------------------------------------
09/06/2017 13:10:07
File Name: \\location\folderpath\subfolder\2.txt
File Size: 153.0 bytes
File Created: 2017-01-26 14:29:59
File Last Modified: 2017-01-26 14:28:39
```

But when I replaced the string.format with json dumps the looping doesn't work

```
string_output = ""
my_paths = []
for p in ['\\\location\\folderpath\\subfolder\\']:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(p):
        my_paths.append(filenames)
        for filename in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            if last_modified(full_path) < threshold:
                string_output=json.dumps({'Timestamp: ':timestamp, 'FileName : ':full_path, 'File Size : ':file_size(full_path), 'File Created : ':created(full_path),'File Last Modified : ':last_modified(full_path)  }, sort_keys=False, indent=8)    
print string_output;
```

Json output with extra backslash (same as input) and only one record

```
{
        "FileName : ": "\\\location\\folderpath\\subfolder\2.txt", 
        "Timestamp: ": "Timestamp: 09/06/2017 13:10:07", 
        "File Created : ": "2017-01-26 14:29:59",  
        "File Last Modified : ": "2017-01-26 13:14:11", 
        "File Size : ": "48.0 bytes"
}
```

How to make json.dumps to list all the files instead of 1 result and output without extra backslash?

Comment: In the first example, you're appending to `string_output` using `+=`. In the second example, you're *assigning* using `=` so you're replacing whatever used to be there...so of course you only see a single record of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep reassigning `string_output` in your code that uses `json`, whereas you concatenate strings in the original code. That means the last file that passes your conditional `last_modified(full_path) < threshold` would end up being the only one output.

A modified version of your snippet that does `string_output +=` should achieve what you want.

```
string_output = ""
my_paths = []
for p in ['\\\location\\folderpath\\subfolder\\']:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(p):
        my_paths.append(filenames)
        for filename in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            if last_modified(full_path) < threshold:
                string_output += json.dumps({'Timestamp: ':timestamp, 'FileName : ':full_path, 'File Size : ':file_size(full_path), 'File Created : ':created(full_path),'File Last Modified : ':last_modified(full_path)  }, sort_keys=False, indent=8)    

print string_output
```

If you want to normalize your paths so they don't have extra `\`, you could do a replace on the `full_path` like shown below.

```
if last_modified(full_path) < threshold:
    string_output += json.dumps(
        {'Timestamp': timestamp, 
         'FileName': full_path.replace('\\\\', '\\'),
         'File Size': file_size(full_path),
         'File Created': created(full_path),
         'File Last Modified': last_modified(full_path)
        }, sort_keys=False, indent=8)
```

Comment: works well but replace('\\','\') gave me an error "eol while scanning string literal"

Comment: @Prime - whoops, updated - have to escape ``\`` as it's a special character in Python strings.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious issue to listing all the files instead of only one is that you are reassigning with `=` instead of `+=`.

However, `+=` probably isn't the best approach either.  The reason is that strings are immutable, so each time you call `+=` on a string, it returns a copy of the original string plus the bit added.  For large strings with many additions, this can adversely affect performance.

I would recommend creating a list to hold all the string additions, and then joing the results once done.

```
line_separator = '----------------------------------------\n'
results = []
for p in [...]:
    ...
    if last_modified(full_path) < threshold:
        results.append(json.dumps({'Timestamp: ':timestamp, 'FileName : ':full_path, 'File Size : ':file_size(full_path), 'File Created : ':created(full_path),'File Last Modified : ':last_modified(full_path)  }, sort_keys=False, indent=8) )

line_seprator.join(results)
```